# how to make decryption of HashPassword BCrypt in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, encryption, bcrypt, password-encryption, password-hash

how to make decryption of HashPassword BCrypt in VB.NET?.

the problem is If the user forgets the password then I can do decryption from HashPassword stored in the database or is there any other solution please guide me.

Thanks

```
Public Class frmLoginRegister
    Private uService As New UserService()
    Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
        'add dapper logics here 
        Dim users = uService.GetDTOUsersByUsername(txtUsername.Text)
        Dim verified As Boolean = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(txtPassword.Text, users.Password)
        If users.Username = txtUsername.Text AndAlso verified Then
            Program.Userinformation = users
            MessageBox.Show("Successfull, Welcome " & users.RoleName)
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
            Me.Hide()
            Call (New FrmMain()).ShowDialog()
            Environment.Exit(0)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login details")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub BtnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRegister.Click
        'check if username exists
        Dim user = uService.GetUserByUsername(txtUsername.Text)
        If user IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("User already exists")
            Return
        End If
        'insert new record
        uService.InserUser(New Users() With {
            .Username = txtUsername.Text,
            .Password = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(txtPassword.Text),
             .RoleID = CInt(txtRoleID.Text)
        })
        'show success message
        MessageBox.Show("User successfully added")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The whole point of hashing is that it is a one-way process. You cannot go backwards from the hash to the original value. When hashing passwords for user management, here's how it works. When the user registers, you hash the password they provide and store that hash. When the user logs in, you hash the password they provide and compare that hash to the hash stored in the database. If they match, you know that the correct password was provided. If the user forgets their password then you need to reset it to a new one. The old one cannot be recovered.

Comment: You can't. That's the point.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , 
thank you for your response. This means that the solution is that I have to reset or update to a new HashPassword

Comment: @siwa86 Correct

Comment: You also have to ask yourself: What if you *could* do what you're asking for? What if you *could* retrieve a user's password? That would be a very, *very*, **very**, bad thing.